# Can you identify this fencer

Tags: minifigure-identification

Can anyone identify this hair piece and head? I did a search for moustache on Bricklink and couldn't find it.

[image]

Comment: 'Allo. My name is Inigo Montoya.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The head is

[part # 3626bpx129 : Minifigure, Head Moustache Black Bangs, Striped Sideburns, Cleft Chin Pattern - Blocked Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=39009#T=C&C=3)

[image: 3626bpx129]

Hair

- [Part# 40251 : Minifigure, Hair Female Mid-Length](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40251#T=C)

[image: 40251]

The rapier (sword) is from [Brickarms](http://brickarms.com/Rapier.php)